# Why can't I use weakly-named assembly in strongly-named one

Tags: .net, clr

I have simple .csproj which is signed with a key. When I installed package form nudget packet manager I got exception that: Cannot load file 'XXXX' or one of it's dependencies. Package with strong name is required (HRESULT: 0x80131044)

When I disabled signing my own .dll everything works. 
I am reading about strongly named assemblies and GAC but I don't see explanation why I can't use not signed package in signed one. Any idea? Am I missing something?

Comment: the main point of strong-naming is to have confidence that you're running the code that you *expected* to be running; if your *dependent assemblies* weren't also strong-named, this would completely negate the point of that, as once you've let one unknown in: it is game over

Comment: Ok I see, but is there some doc where that is explained? and what about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions , does it mean that signing assembly is pointless because someone can change it?

Comment: people can't sign an assembly without the private key; if you've distributed your private keys, then yes someone else can build it and sign it *with the same key* in a way that would satisfy the loader; there are lots of discussions on the pros/cons of strong naming - lots more than I can cover here; short version: if you're writing a public library: strong name it; if your API framework *requires* strong naming: strong name it; otherwise... meh, do whatever; these days, the tooling usually automatically deals with the painful bits like "assembly binding redirects"

Comment: Ok I see, thank you for explanation:)